# Create data without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to insert data into my database using ASP.NET MVC without Entity Framework and it doesn't work.

I tried these tutorials:

- [InsertUpdateDelete in ASP.NET MVC 5 without Entity Framework | C# Tutorial](http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/mvc-articles/insert-update-delete-in-asp-net-mvc-5-without-entity-framework/)
- [ASP.Net MVC CRUD Operation without Entity Framework - YouTube](https://youtu.be/XMDAXuoOO_w?list=PLg_XBENeKGJsx3TnuiIYQHDSUsVwesU4Q)

This is my controller:

```
public class AdresaController : Controller
{
   private OracleConnection conn;

    public AdresaController()
    {
        Connection connection = new Connection();
        conn = connection.GetOracleConnection();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Adresa/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AdresaModel obAdresa)
    {
        try
        {
            AdresaRepository x = new AdresaRepository(conn);
            string result = x.CreateAdr(obAdresa);
            ViewData["result"] = result;
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my repository:

```
public class AdresaRepository
{
    private OracleConnection oracleConnection;

    public AdresaRepository(OracleConnection oracleConnection)
    {
        this.oracleConnection = oracleConnection;
    }

    public string CreateAdr(AdresaModel obAdresa)//
    {
        string result = "";

        try
        {
            string oString = "insert into adresa(id_adresa, strada, nr_str, bloc, localitate_id_loc) values(@id_adresa, @strada, @nr_str, @bloc, @localitate_id_loc)";
            var cmdc = new OracleCommand(oString, oracleConnection);

            cmdc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmdc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@id_adresa", obAdresa.IdAdresa));
            cmdc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@strada", obAdresa.Strada));
            cmdc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@nr_str", obAdresa.NrStrada));
            cmdc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@bloc", obAdresa.Bloc));
            cmdc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@localitate_id_loc", obAdresa.IdLoc));

            oracleConnection.Open();
            result = cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
            oracleConnection.Close();

            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            return result = "";
        }
        finally
        {
            oracleConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my model:

```
public class AdresaModel
{
    public int IdAdresa { get; set; }
    public string Strada { get; set; }
    public string NrStrada { get; set; }
    public string Bloc { get; set; }
    public int IdLoc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: If there was an exception, you are throwing the details of the exception in your `catch` block. Don't do that. You need to see what the exception deatils are in order to figure out what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: if you are using an insert query then command type cannot be stored procedure and vice-versa.

Comment: It doesn't throw any exception. But when I insert the data in form, nothing happens...

Comment: How do you know it doesn't throw any exception?

Comment: `catch
        {
            return result = "";
        }` is discarding any exception you might get. If you're going to catch the exception and suppress it like this, you should at least log it to disk for future reference. Otherwise it's impossible to debug anything.

Comment: i commented "try{" and catch block and then i run...

Comment: I have this exception : {"ORA-00936: missing expression"}, in repository, to  `result = cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kashi_rock is on the right track but didn't explain the issue very well.  When you execute a command, you can either set the `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` and the `CommandText` to the name of a stored procedure or you can set `CommnadType` to `Text` (which is the default) and the `CommandText` to a SQL statement.  You are mixing and matching.  You are providing inline SQL but saying that you want to use a stored procedure.  Basically, get rid of this line:

```
cmdc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

I find it very difficult to believe that no exception was thrown.  It should have tried to tell you that there was no stored procedure with the name you specified or the like.  You need to up your exception handling game or you'll be mystified by other things that seem to just not work with no indication of why.

Comment: This is my exception : An exception of type "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: No surprise that there actually was an exception thrown.  Did you do as I suggested and remove that line?  Was there still an exception thrown after that?

Comment: By the way, I don't really use Oracle but I'm not sure that the Oracle provider supports "@" as a parameter prefix. I think you may need to use "p" or ":" instead.

Comment: It worked... I used ":" instead of "@" and i changed a little bit... Thanks:D